# OIDC for mobile app with PKCE and client_secret

Tags: oidc

I came across [this](https://medium.com/klaxit-techblog/openid-connect-for-mobile-apps-fcce3ec3472) article. In there the author suggests to use PKCE which is recommended by [RFC 8252](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252). But what I am a little bit confused about that the author also uses an application server that has the client_secret.

Are both client_secret and PKCE both adding security?

Or is PKCE just the replacement for the client_secret for public clients?

I would be interested in attack scenarios where the client_secret helps but PKCE does not.

Answer (score 0):

Without PKCE, a malicious mobile app could intercept an authorization code intended for the legitimate mobile app on the victim's device, as explained [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7636#section-1). It could then forward the authorization code to another client (for example, the legitimate mobile app on the attacker's device). And since both client-instances of the legitimate mobile app use the same client ID and secret, the attacker can exchange the authorization code for an access token on behalf of the victim, even if the secret is only known to the attacker's legitimate mobile app (and not to the attacker as a person).

PKCE is needed to prevent this kind of attack, even in the presence of client secrets that are shared by many client-instances.

Conversely, without a client secret, a malicious app could pretend to be the legitimate one and start the authorization flow even with PKCE. It need not intercept an authorization code or forward it, but it must convince the victim to mistake it for the legitimate app, for example, through a faked web page.

Although less likely, this attack scenario cannot be prevented by PKCE, but only by a client secret that is unknown to the attacker (such as a secret stored only on the server of the legitimate web app).